# Edit Database entry with AJAX and return edited data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following form:

```
 <?php 
        echo "<strong>".$Event_data_fetched['event_subject']."</strong><br />";

        echo   '<form id="Event_Editing" action="#" method="post">
                    Event-Type:<br />
                    <select name="edited_event_type">
                        <option>'.$Event_type.'</option>
                        <option>'.$Unselected_1.'</option>
                        <option>'.$Unselected_2.'</option>
                    </select><br /><br />

                    Event-Subject:<br />
                    <input type="text" name="edited_event_subject" value="'.$Event_data_fetched['event_subject'].'"/><br /><br />

                    <input id="Edit_Event" type="submit" name="Edit_Event" value="Speichern">
                </form>';               
    ?>
```

The form is meant to display data, from a row in the database and offer the user the option to edit said data. And I already have a query that handles the data and rewrites the edited data in the Database, when the form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['Edit_Event'])){
        $New_Type_Value = $_POST['edited_event_type'];
        $New_Subject_Value = $_POST['edited_event_subject'];

        if($New_Type_Value == "Meet"){
            $New_Type_Value = 1;
        }
        else if($New_Type_Value == "Clubday"){
            $New_Type_Value = 2;
        }
        else if($New_Type_Value == "Surprise-Event"){
            $New_Type_Value = 3;
        }

        $edit_data_query = "UPDATE b6vjp_event
                            SET event_type_id = $New_Type_Value,
                                event_subject = '$New_Subject_Value'
                            WHERE id = $Event_id";

        mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $edit_data_query);
    }
```

Now I want to put this block of code into a separate .php File.

My ultimate goal is to post the form to an AJAX script, that then sends the data to a separate file, where it edits the DB with the new data. After it has been inserted the newly edited data should be given back and written back into the form. I also need to post a variable with the ID of the row. Otherwise, the query won't know where to insert the edited data.

I googled a bunch and tried a lot of things, but don't seem to find anything specifically working for me. I did stumble across a code that looks like a good start but not what I want to do:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#Event_Editing").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
    var $form = $( this ),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
    var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

    /* Alerts the results */
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
    });
    });
</script>
```

My biggest Problem is that I'm not that good at AJAX. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Hi, take a look at the official documentation [Ajax jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) I think it's very useful and clear. At the end of the page you have an example of an Ajax POST (you only need to put your own url and you own data variables). Also notice that, doing this with Ajax, you don't need to update the form values (the page won't refresh, so the form will stay as the user left it).

Comment: @IonGorostizuAlbeniz I have since found out that I dont need to use AJAX to do this :). But since AJAX does look like a real nifty thing, I will save your link and look into AJAX. Thank you for the Link and the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current code works fine without any issue then,

you can just use
`echo json_encode($_POST);` at the end of your code in PHP file to return data that you have updated in your DB.

In your javascript code try,

```
posting.done(function( data ) {
       //Prits data you returned on console.
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Oh god youre right. Im such a moron. I even save the edited data, in my 2nd block of code, into 2 variables. I could just echo those out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the AJAX call like so:

```
<?php 
echo "<strong>".$Event_data_fetched['event_subject']."</strong><br />";

echo   '<form id="Event_Editing" action="#" method="post">
            Event-Type:<br />
            <select name="edited_event_type">
                <option>'.$Event_type.'</option>
                <option>'.$Unselected_1.'</option>
                <option>'.$Unselected_2.'</option>
            </select><br /><br />

            Event-Subject:<br />
            <input type="text" name="edited_event_subject" value="'.$Event_data_fetched['event_subject'].'"/><br /><br />

            <input id="Edit_Event" type="submit" name="Edit_Event" value="Speichern" onclick='editData();'>
        </form>';        

?>


<script>

    function editData(){
        var value = document.getElementById('Event_Editing').value;

        $.ajax({
            url : 'your-backend-file-with-DB-Query.php',
            method : 'POST',// OR GET
            data: {value:value},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }

        }); 

    }

</script>
```

Then in your backend file you can receive the values like so:

```
<?php

/*CONNECTION TO DB*/

$value = $_POST['value'];

/*Now you can use this value in your Query and update the database*/

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Sadly another user already showed me how to do it without using AJAX, so Ill do it without for now. But I bookmarked this post. I do want to do it with AJAX at some point, just because its good training. So thanks alot for the answer!